# Are there different color UV Dyes?

Tags: fluid-leak

I know there are these UV dye additives that can be added to oil or power steering fluid and other types of fluid. But I’m worried that all the UV dyes are the same color making them indistinguishable from each other if added to the different fluids of a vehicle. Ideally there would be a red UV dye and a yellow and green one. If that existed we could assign different UV dyes to the different fluids and test right away by color when a leak presents itself and know what was leaking very quickly.

Does such a UV dye coloration exist or are they all that fluorescent yellow color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While yellow seems to be the prevalent color of dye, it isn't the only color available. A quick [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultraviolet+leak+dye) turned up this kit (**NOTE:** I have no affiliation with this company or product.):

[image]

It has four different colors which can be used for different fluid leaks.

That said, different dye colors really aren't needed if you understand how to use them. Dye kits really aren't for detecting what's leaking, but more for figuring out what an individual leak is coming from. There are only so many different types of fluids a vehicle has. It is very easy to differentiate between them if you know what you're looking for and where the leak (general vicinity) is located. The two liquids which might be confused are power steering and automatic transmission fluid, because some manufacturers still use tranny fluid in the power steering. The difference here is the location of where a leak might occur as they usually aren't co-located. Engine oil and anti-freeze are the other two big fluids. They are very easy to tell apart, especially while dripping.

Bottom line is, dye kits are usually used when it is really hard to tell where the leak is occurring, not for figuring out what is leaking.

Comment: *"if you know what you're looking for"* and what you're **feeling** for. Oils feel different to brake fluid, which feels different to coolant, which is surprisingly slippery for something water-based, much more so than screenwash.  I happen to have screenwash with UV-reactive dye in in, goodness know why the manufacturer did that.  Of course if dying fluids yourself you need to consider solubility in the fluid.

Comment: @ChrisH - Absolutely

Comment: That slipperiness of coolant caught me by surprise, I got totally fooled by its slipperiness and was caught off guard that something water soluble would be so slick. It's a different kind of slickness of course but I guess in all these years I've never managed to actually touch coolant before. Kind of startling.

Comment: Linking to the product above for the convenient reference `TPUV92
MULTI-COLORED FLUID DYE UV LEAK DETECTION KIT` https://tracerproducts.com/multi-colored-fluid-dye-uv-leak-detection-kit

Comment: @jxramos - I didn't provide a link to the product mainly because that sort of implies an endorsement. My only point for providing the picture was to show there are multiple dye colors. I provided a Google search link which has multiple kits like the one in the picture. With the Google link, there really isn't a need for us to point out the product in the picture.

Comment: yah I can understand that angle, however this product seems in a league of its own. It's pretty specialized stuff and they may have a patent on the idea or  something because it doesn't appear anyone else is doing likewise with the color mapping. It's pricy stuff too just about $[300](https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/c/tracer-products/tracer-products-kit/trc0/tpuv92)

Comment: @ChrisH I wonder if the dye in the screenwash (which I presume is windshield wiping fluid) was to serve as some kind of [optical brightener](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/optical-brightener) sort of like how you find in laundry detergent

Comment: @jxramos yes, screenwash is the stuff you put in the windscreen washer tank. Mine is the colour of yellow highlighter pen (rather than the bluish white of optical brighteners), and optical brighteners wouldn't serve any useful purpose here

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the only color used is the one that reflects ultraviolet lights making it easily visible under a black light. If there are multiple leaks, each leak can be traced to their source by using the proper procedure. Most importantly cleaning the engine before testing. There are solutions to clean the dye itself if necessary. With proper application the need for different colors probably would not be warranted. There definitely are different types of dyes. Some are oil based, water based and another compatable with refrigerant.

Comment: Crucially, it's not *reflecting* UV - you can't see UV, so you can't see reflected UV.  It's absorbing the UV and fluorescing, i.e. re-emitting light that you can see.

Comment: @ChrisH - Actually, some people *can see* into the UV spectrum, especially those who have had cataract surgery ... but I take your point about it actually being the fluorescing properties of the dye under UV light being what is normally seen.